# How do I populate only as many rows in Excel as the value in a particular cell?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have an Excel worksheet, and I'm looking to do this:

1. I input a number into a cell to indicate my age (18-99).
2. I input a second number into another cell to indicate my annual expenses.
3. The output is that the worksheet will show me cumulative expenses for as many years as I've indicated in the first field. This means that if I entered 18 for my age, the worksheet will only show/populate 18 rows. If I change the number to 40, then 40 rows will be populated based on the same formula each time. I just want to be able to only see as many rows as my age.

I have looked for videos and only Q&A for this, but haven't seen something that addresses this.

Comment: There is no actual question. Please can you edit your question according to [aks] a question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work with a Simple If Condition.

Simple If Conditions : `=IF(E2<$B$1,$B$2,0)` with the formula dragged down.

[File Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JrsT33qF8Qv6nK1zhfdPTl7n36_NiCMX)

[image]

You can play with If Condition.

Comment: This seems correct, but maybe been downvoted because a link to a file will eventually stop working. Consider to update your question with actual formulas to replicate, not only by OP but future users :)

Comment: @JvdV , I added the Code. But people should comment on why they downvoted the answer

Comment: Yes that would be helpfull to improve posts.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you for the response!

Comment: Done. Apologize, wasn't aware that there was an "Accept" button here.